# Bot Service Web App not supported in Resource Group with existing Linux ASP

Tags: botframework, azure-resource-group

When attempting to create a Bot Service hosted on a Web App I am encountering an error when attempt to deploy to a Resource Group where an existing Linux App Service Plan exists. I am not trying to host my Bot Service on that ASP just simply trying to deplpoy a new ASP for Bot Service and am getting the following error:

[image]

In consideration of Resource Group design if I want any Bot Service Web Apps is it true that I cannot deploy them in a Resource Group with a Linux ASP?

Comment: According to this github issue, this was true in the past, but that was some time ago so I do not know if this is still an issue. https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/issues/536

Comment: Thanks @billoverton. I will try to follow-up over there

Comment: @ToriFuller - Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Still an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub issue that Bill Overton linked to describes a problem where people were getting an error message about not being able to create a Windows ASP in a resource group with a Linux ASP even though the resource group had no Linux ASP. That is the problem that was supposedly fixed. The limitation remains of not being able to have a Windows ASP and a Linux ASP in the same resource group, and if you want that to change there is [an existing post in the feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/37287583-allow-a-linux-and-windows-app-service-plan-to-exis) where you can voice your opinion.